# ABAP: pass data type to form

Tags: abap

I want to pass my own datatype to a form - but it doesn´t work:

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF my_type,
     v1 TYPE i,
     v2 TYPE i,
   END OF my_type. 


PERFORM calc using ...some parameters... .

FORM calc using ...some parameters... .

DATA values TYPE my_type " <- ERROR type my_type does not exist

...some code...

ENDFORM.
```

Comment: I suspect you might have a typo in your original code. The pseudo-code you show in the question should work.

Comment: the original code is located in a function module - does this make any difference?

Comment: Yes. A function module is its own programm (the name is SAPL...function group name...). Each function module is its own include. There is no relation between a normal report and a function group. If you need to share a type definition you should define it as a global type in SE11. (Maybe a shared include will also work. But I'm not sure and I don't recommend it).

Comment: Please post an actual example of the code that is not working, not some snippet that has been abbreviated to irrelevance.

Comment: @knut thx, se11 helped me. I defined my structure as global type. Now I can use it in the function module.

Comment: I made an answer of my comment. You may accept it and the question is answered. Is your code inside a function group or is your code splitted in function group and function module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remark: Based on more information in comments: The code is defined in a function module.

A function module is its own programm (the name is `SAPL`...function group name...). Each function module is its own include.

If you define a type in a report, a function module can't know the type definition. If you need to share a type definition between a reports and function modules (groups), you should define it as a global type in SE11.

If you run your code only inside a function module, you may define types in the top include of the function group. But you should not use this definition in the function module interfaces.